# Change Hover color of categories in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, css

you can see Categories in left side, If you hover  category names , you can see it will change to pink color, how to chagne the color from pink to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.vnav > .menu-item-depth-0 > .em-catalog-navigation > .level0:hover > a{
    color: #000;
}
```

To change shopping cart color

```
.top-cart-inner .top-cart {
border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
background-position: 15px 15px;
background-color: #000;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 13px 12px 12px;
}
```